# Rails3 - RSpec - How to set request.env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I try to stub my request.env

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AuthenticationController do
  render_views
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe "GET 'create'" do
    @request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
```

results in

```
`method_missing': undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I put data into my request.env object before calling the method?
Also using request.env = does not work.

Comment: have you tried accessing ENV['RACK_ENV'] ? Your code also has @request.env and not request.env, but that may be a rails thing, I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: @request and request do both not work. I will look into the ENV solution